# How to populate a form from a list to update in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to angular. I have created reactive forms. I need to populate the form with values from a GET REST call so that I can update.

The list and form are different components. Clicking on edit on list should take me to a new url with populated values. Should I implement it with @Input or observables? Kindly point to some examples.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the value of a control built via reactive forms paradigm, use the [`AbstractControl#setValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValue) or [`AbstractControl#patchValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#patchValue) methods. The first argument is the new value you want to set.

Here's an example of usage.

```
form = this.fb.group({
  username: ''
})

ngOnInit() {
  this.form.setValue({username: 'Name'})
}
```

The difference between `setValue` and `patchValue` is that `setValue` is stricter: it won't allow any missing or extra fields on case of updating `FormGroup`'s value. For example, say we're given the form built like this.

```
form = this.fb.group({
  username: '',
  password: '',
})
```

And we want to update only the password. The following will work.

```
this.form.patchValue({password: '123456'})
```

But the following will fail because we didn't provide a value for the `username` control.

```
this.form.setValue({password: '123456'}) // runtime Angular error
```

Comment: This worked....
also used 

 `onClick(id:any){
    this.router.navigate(['component_name',id.id]);
  }`

to communicate the id value between list component to form component. Using single id loaded the entire object on the URL, using id.id only loaded the id in the URL.
Further I was able to do a get call from the form component, to get the object in the form component.